# change font color of meta.function-call visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to configure the font color after the dot **"."** when a method is called after a parent class rute **"meta.function-call"** g.e:

```
import os

os.path()
```

in this case **path**, but i want to customize it for everything else, as others text editors for example **sublimeText**. Can't find anything related on the web

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode color theme methods calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60027374/vscode-color-theme-methods-calls)

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example that will color the function name and parentheses (the theme name level can be omitted to apply to all themes):

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Atom One Light]": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": [
                    "meta.function-call.generic.python",
                    "punctuation.definition.arguments.begin.python",
                    "punctuation.definition.arguments.end.python"
                ], /*functions()*/
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#0184BC"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

You can use the *Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes* (enter in the Run Commands menu) to identify each separate token:

[image]