# VSCode color theme methods calls

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, textmate

I'm trying to change method calls color in VSCode. I know I can change the Function scope color as follewed:

```
{
  "name": "Function call", 
  "scope": "meta.function-call.object", 
  "settings": {
    "foreground": "#e26f60"
  }
}
```

Is there an equivalent for method calls. I would like to only highlight the **foo_method**() in the following code:

```
class Foo():
    def foo_method(self):
        print("Called Foo from class")

foo_object = Foo()
foo_object.foo_method()
```

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the method call to `foo_method` is:

```
meta.function-call.generic.python
meta.function-call.python
meta.member.access.python
source.python
```

So to just target methods, try using a more specific scope selector in your theme. For example, `meta.member.access meta.function-call` will select all `meta.function-call` scopes under `meta.member.access` scopes:

```
{
  "name": "Function call", 
  "scope": "meta.member.access meta.function-call",
  "settings": {
    "foreground": "#e26f60"
  }
}
```

[image]

(you may need to further tweak the scope selector based on your specific needs)

Comment: Thanks Matt. It's working to highlight the method. I'm not so familiar with scope selector. I might tweak it a bit as I don't want to also highlight the parameters inside the parenthesis. Is it possible? Where can I find good info about scope selector? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways to do it for python, it might give you an idea: setting a text mate theming rule is not beginner friendly to play around.
Best way imo to open users/username/.vscode/extensions folder. And search the your favorite theme you want to edit. Make a backup of the file and play around.
Most of them doesn't have specific code for method call. But you can add following to your code for method calls and change to hex color value with your preferred color.

```
    {            
        "scope": "meta.function-call.generic.python",
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#fad599",
            "fontStyle": ""
        }
    },
```